# Break a string and reverse each element of it

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I'm learning data and algorithm, here is the question I met

Question:Write a short recursive Python function that takes a character string s and
outputs its reverse. For example, the reverse of pots&pans would be
snap&stop .

```
a="pots&pans"
b=a.split("&")
c=[]
c=list(b)
def reverse(data,leng,leng2,index,count):
    rev=(leng-1)-count
    if count<leng/2:
        temp=data[index][count]
        data[index][count]=data[index][rev]
        data[index][rev]=temp
    if index==leng2:
        print(data[index-1]+"&"+data[index])
    return reverse(data,leng,leng2,index+1,count)
reverse(c,4,2,0,0)
```

I got an error here

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

My initial thought is that str is immutable. So it is better to store it in an list and do the operations. However, it met some problem when I trying to assign str to a list. Any solution to this?

Comment: `print(  "pots&pans"[::-1])`? - not recursive though

Comment: why do you call `reverse` with `c` ... an empty list?

Comment: why do you say _the revers of pots&pans would be snap&stop_ - shouldnt that be stop&snap from your coding logic?

Comment: `b` is already a list - why do you copy it into `c`?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I'm confusing though, b is a list but still got error to use b to do operations. Here is what my problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a="pots&pans"
b=a.split("&")

def reverse(word):

    if not word:
        return ""

    return reverse(word[1:]) + word[0]

result = reverse(b[1]) + "&" + reverse(b[0])

print(result)
```

If you want one recursion to also reverse all the words position:

```
a="pots&pans&hello&hi"
b=a.split("&")

def reverse(lis):

    if not lis:
        return ""

    if type(lis) == list and len(lis) == 1:
        return reverse(lis[0])

    if type(lis) == str:
        return reverse(lis[1:]) + lis[0]

    if type(lis) == list:
        return reverse(lis[1:]) + "&" + reverse(lis[0])

print(reverse(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

One recursive approach would be to append the first character to the reverse of the rest of the string:

```
def rev(s): return rev(s[1:])+s[0] if s else ""
```

output:

```
rev("pots&pans")

'snap&stop'
```

You could also do this without indexing using parameter unpacking:

```
def rev(first,*rest): return rev(*rest)+first if rest else first

rev(*"pots&pans")

'snap&stop'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this：

```py
a="pots&pans"

def reverse(a_string):
    `letter_list = list(a_string)`
    `letter_list.reverse()`
    `return(''.join(letter_list))`

print(reverse(a))
```

Comment: Read the question, please. "Write a short *recursive* Python function..."

Comment: also asumably: words should be reversed, but position inside the string should stay the same

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, this is first draft of my code. I didn't remove any errors. Just follow the questions, not my code